# Power Apps Converted Multi-select Checkboxes clear out after an item has been edited

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, power-platform

I have a Power Apps form (customized SharePoint form), where I have a requirement to display a multi-select dropdown (Region) as checkboxes.  The data submits correctly, and when a submitted item is reopened, the checkboxes still retain their values.  BUT, if a submitted item is edited (re-submitted), the column value disappears, and the checkboxes clear out.  Here's how I have it set up:

- Multi-select Choice field (Region).  Added 5 checkboxes to the data card.
- Checkbox properties:

  ```
  OnCheck & Uncheck: 
                ClearCollect(
                Region5,
                If(Checkbox2.Value, "UO"),
                If(Checkbox2_1.Value, "USH"),
                If(Checkbox2_2.Value, "USJ"),
                If(Checkbox2_3.Value, "USS"),
                If(Checkbox2_4.Value, "Other"));
           ClearCollect(Region5,Filter(Region5, !IsBlank(Value)))

   Default: Self.Text in Concat(ThisItem.Region, Value&",")
  ```
- `DatacardValue` Properties:
  `Defaultselecteditems`:
  Region5
- Datacard Properties:
  `Default`: Thisitem.Region
  `Update`: Region5

Region 5 is the name of my collection for the "Region" Choice (checkbox) field.

Again, this set of properties successfully logs the selected checkbox(es) into the SharePoint list.  But when a user opens an existing item, modifies it, then clicks the 'Submit' button again (OnSelect - SubmitForm(SharePointForm1), that value clear out in SharePoint and the form.

Any help would be great. This is driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to populate the `Region5` collection when opening list form in edit mode. Example: try setting `SharePointIntegration.OnEdit` to `ClearCollect(Region5, ThisItem.Region)`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I just added that code you suggested to OnEdit property for SharePointIntegration and got an error:  "The function ClearCollect has some invalid arguments".  And "Name isn't valid.  'ThisItem' isn't recognized.

Comment: Try: `ClearCollect(Region5, SharePointIntegration.Selected.Region);`.

Comment: That did it.  THANK YOU.  I ended up using this in my OnEdit -EditForm(SharePointForm1);
ClearCollect(Region5, SharePointIntegration.Selected.Region).  Works perfectly

Comment: Yes, `EditForm(SharePointForm1);` is already there by default. Glad it worked for you. I have added same as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to populate the `Region5` collection again when opening the SharePoint list form in edit mode.

Try using below formula in `SharePointIntegration.OnEdit` property:

```
EditForm(SharePointForm1);
ClearCollect(Region5, SharePointIntegration.Selected.Region);
```

Where `SharePointForm1` is the name of form control and `Region` is the name of your choice column in the list.